# search location and map type features are not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to make search location feature and map type change feature work on my android google maps api aplication, but when I tap on the buttons related to the search and to the map change the application stops running.
The layout of the buttons and the functions are well implemented, I can't see where the error is. Does anyone know what is missing to make these two funcionalities work properly?

```
Manifest file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dborahramos.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBVCTEWR6ifov2W_9itWuUfBvptd8MoA7U" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Here is activity maps:

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/TFaddress" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search"
                android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:onClick="onSearch" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Map Type"
                android:id="@+id/Btype"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:onClick="changeType" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="450dp" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="^"
                    android:id="@+id/Bzoomin"
                    android:onClick="onZoom" />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="v"
                    android:id="@+id/Bzoomout"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onZoom" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

And here are search location and map type functions on maps activity.java.

    public void onSearch(View view)
        {
            EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
            String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addressList = null;
            if(location != null || !location.equals(""))
            {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 1);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            }
        }

    public void changeType(View view)
    {
        if(mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
        {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
        else
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check your intent requests.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#intent_requests):

> In order to launch Google Maps with an intent you must first create an Intent object, specifying its action, URI and package.
>
> - **Action**: All Google Maps intents are called as a View action — `ACTION_VIEW`.
> - **URI**: Google Maps intents use URI encoded strings that specify a desired action, along with some data with which to perform the action.
> - **Package**: Calling `setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")` will ensure that the Google Maps app for Android handles the Intent.

Furthermore,

> To verify that an app is available to receive the intent, call `resolveActivity()` on your `Intent` object. If the result is non-null, there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to call `startActivity()`. If the result is null, you should not use the intent and, if possible, you should disable the feature that invokes the intent.

Detailed information and examples can be found in [Google Maps Intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#top_of_page).